# Conditional left join on max date and where clause in second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to join a customer table with sales table where I show the list of all customers in database and any paid sale the customer might have in the sales tables. Now a customer can have multiple sales rows in the sales table.
This is an example sales record of one customer with multiple sales in the sale tables

[image]

while extracting this record I would like to get only the MAX (q_saledatetime) WHERE the q_paidamount is > 0.
***as in show me the last time this customer made a payment to us***. So in this case row 2 where they paid 8.90 is what I would like to get for that customer. *If a customer has no record in the sales table, show their name/details on the list either way.*

My failure at the moment is how to include the where clause of the paid amount + max date column.

ATTEMPT A

```
select DISTINCT ON (q_customer.q_code)
q_customer.q_code, q_customer.q_name,  -- customer info  
MAX(q_saleheader.q_saledatetime) AS latestDate, q_saleheader.q_paidamount  -- saleheader info
FROM q_customer
LEFT JOIN q_saleheader ON (q_customer.q_code =  q_saleheader.q_customercode) 
group by q_customer.q_code, q_customer.q_name , q_saleheader.q_saledatetime, q_saleheader.q_paidamount
order by q_customer.q_code ASC
```

which results in

[image]

so for Fred Blogg is picking up details from row 4 instead of 2 ***(first image)***. As there's no rule for q_paidamount at this point

ATTEMPT B

```
SELECT 
customer.q_code, customer.q_name,  -- customer info
sale.q_saledatetime, sale.q_paidamount  -- sale info        
FROM q_customer customer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM q_saleheader WHERE q_saledatetime = 
(SELECT MAX(q_saledatetime) FROM q_saleheader b1 where q_paidamount > 0 )) 
sale ON sale.q_customercode = customer.q_code
```

which results in

[image]

This doesnt seem to be getting any information from the sale table at all.

***Update:***

After having a closer look at my first attempt I amended the statement and came up with this solution which achieves the same results as Michal's answer. I just curious to know is there any pitfalls or perfomance disadvantages with the following way.

```
select DISTINCT ON (q_customer.q_code)
q_customer.q_code, q_customer.q_name,  -- customer info  
q_saleheader.q_saledatetime, q_saleheader.q_paidamount  -- saleheader   info
FROM q_customer
LEFT JOIN q_saleheader ON (q_customer.q_code =   q_saleheader.q_customercode AND 
q_saleheader.q_paidamount > 0 ) 
group by q_customer.q_code, q_customer.q_name ,  q_saleheader.q_saledatetime, 
q_saleheader.q_paidamount
order by q_customer.q_code ASC, q_saleheader.q_saledatetime DESC
```

main change was adding AND q_saleheader.q_paidamount > 0 on the join and q_saleheader.q_saledatetime DESC to make sure are getting the top row of that related data. As mentioned both Michal's answer and this solution achieve the same results. Just curious about pitfalls in either of the two ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT c.q_code,
       c.q_name,
       CASE WHEN q_saledatetime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN q_saledatetime END q_saledatetime,
       q_paidamount
FROM (
    SELECT c.q_code, 
           c.q_name,
           coalesce(s.q_saledatetime, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') q_saledatetime, --it will indicate customer with no data
           s.q_paidamount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.q_code ORDER BY COALESCE(s.q_saledatetime, '1900-01-01') DESC) rn
    FROM q_customer c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT q_saledatetime,
                      q_paidamount
               FROM q_saleheader
               WHERE q_paidamount > 0) s 
    ON c.q_code = s.q_customercode
) c WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi @Michal, currently getting error on line 1 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "c" ...  LINE 1: SELECT c.q_code,

Comment: thanks @MIchal, worked like a charm. I just needed to add `,q_customercode` in the SELECT within the LEFT JOIN